# Ruby on Rails, LinkedIn:Module error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, linkedin-api

Has any one come across this error?

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for LinkedIn:Module)
```

I think it's related to omniauth and linkedin. Here's my Gemfile:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'linkedin', :git => "git://github.com/redbeard-tech/linkedin.git", :branch => 'jsapi'
```

I'm using:

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249)
- rails 3.0.5

What might be the reason for it?

Answer (score 2):

Check what version of omniauth you are using.  We recently ran into this and it was from our dev environment having omniauth 0.3.x and the new environment getting the new 1.0 release.  On the [omniauth github site](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) it says:

> OmniAuth 1.0 has several breaking changes from version 0.x. You can set the dependency to ~> 0.3.2 if you do not wish to make the more difficult upgrade. See the wiki for more information.

I suspect you're being bitten by that.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it looks like you are calling `LinkedIn.new(...)`, but looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin) it seems like it should be `LinkedIn::Client.new('your_consumer_key', 'your_consumer_secret')`. `LinkedIn` is a module, not a class and therefore doesn't have a `new` method. However, there seems to be class called `Client` defined within this module, which you have to instantiate.