# NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for LinkedIn:Module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just currently trying to follow tutorials to learn ruby and rails etc. So I apologise in advance for the newbie'ness of this question.

I've had a bunch of code dropped on me with instructions to 'get that up and see what it does'.

Its a rails app that was up at one time and now needs to be resurrected.
And I've been hammering at it for a week now.

So, I got the rails app extracted into a folder.. and used rvm to set myself up with

- ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]
- Rails 3.0.7
- On ubuntu 12.04

Cos I was told the app had been a 'rails 3' app.

I had to do a good bit of changing things in the Gemfile as gems were no longer available etc. Spent ages wrestling with Rake errors until I finally forced it back to 0.8.7 and got a db:migrate to work.

And now I can get 'rails server' to startup WEBrick.
However when I point a browser at `http://localhost:3000/` I get the output below.

They thing I'm at a loss with is the "NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for LinkedIn:Module)" as I've grepped and I don't actually have a LinkeIn module in the code.
I just have a Gemfile entry for the

gem "linkedin", "~> 0.4.1"

And I just can't find out where in the code this error is getting thrown from.
If someone could help me identify what file/line that the error is emanating from .. or tell me that its actually coming from the LinkedIn gem than it would be a great help.

Its justkilling me that I can't find out where the code is so that I can go fix it.
The Application Trace on the webpage is blank. 
To me it looks like its happening before the code gets to the controller specified for the root route in the routes.rb.

So, please, any help at all.. how to turn on tracing, where to go to find out whats going on at all..

Thanks

Vida

```
*Console output on browse to root*

/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.7 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-07-30 07:29:01] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-07-30 07:29:01] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [i686-linux]
[2013-07-30 07:29:01] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=13793 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-30 07:29:53 -0600

NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for LinkedIn:Module):


Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (4.3ms)
Rendered /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (9.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for your `LinkedIn:Module`?

Comment: Also I would very strongly recommend that you go through a good tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) rather than try to just figure things out by looking at code. Rails does a lot of things behind the scenes for you, and it will be difficult to understand just by looking at your app's files.

Comment: The thing thats confusing is that I don't have code for LinkedIn:Module in the code I got. So I don't understand where the error is originating.
I am working through tutorials as fast as I can but I'm not seeing anything that would explain to me what happens when a GET to '/' is made.. I think this is all happening before it gets to the code in the app.

Comment: The first thing your app will do is check in the routes.rb file to see where to route a GET request at '/'. This will likely be in there as `root :to => '<controller>#<action>'`. Does your routes.rb file send it to `'LinkedIn#new'`?

Comment: Also, don't "work through tutorials as fast as you can". Take your time and go through a GOOD tutorial that covers everything.  Learning it the right way up front will save you a hell of a lot of time.

Comment: Hi Tyler, and thanks. In the routes.rb file the root :to is not going to LinkedIn#new, its going to a controller like this:
root :to => "career_zoo#index" and in that controller index is 
  def index
    render :layout => "career_zoo/home"
  end

Comment: I tried to put a puts statement in the controller but it doesn't seem to get there...

Comment: So, I'm wondering if there isn't some way to turn on some tracing so I can see the execution order...

Comment: Is the `root :to` at the top of the routes file or are there declarations above it?  If it is first, then try commenting out the linkedin gem, run bundle, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Hi again, yes there are declarations above the root :to. It is actually the last thing in the file.

Comment: OK, I'm just going to leave it that you need to do a good tutorial. Then you would know things like rails goes through the routes file from top to bottom.  Discovering how rails works with the approach you are taking (i.e. trial and error) is going to be a massive slog.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks very much for your time and patience.

Comment: possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284063/ruby-on-rails-linkedinmodule-error

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else happens across this...
Problem was solved with the help of an experienced Rails programmer.
What he did was start from fresh and use rvm to straighten out some issues with my installation.

So, it wasn't a problem in code, per say, but an issue around installing rails etc.

HTH someone.